Formatting E164 phone numbers in data cloud
I'm using data cloud with an external data source (not sales cloud). One of their fields is mobile phone number that I want to format in E164 number format.
The numbers come through in this format: 021 / 646 08 32
and I want to format them so that they are like this: +41216460832
i.e. I want to remove the leading 0 and them remove spaces and the / and add a +41
I've been able to remove the spaces and / and add +41 using this formula:
CONCAT('+41',SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE(sourceField['Telefon_P'],".","")),")","")," ",""),"-",""),".",""),"/",""))
However it leaves the leading zero
Ive been able to get rid of the leading zero using this formula: CONCAT('+41',RIGHT(sourceField['Telefon_P'],14))
But I can't them both to work together?
Any ideas?

you are close -- 1) strip out leading 0 using RIGHT or MID as you know LEN; 2) substitute all noise characters with NULL; 3) prepend with +41

You are correct adding this one as an answer too with full formula for the note.

@raditz2077 I couldn't get that formula to work, I've noticed data cloud doesnt seem to like it if you reference the same field twice in a formula, i could be wrong though. in the end I used this formula:
CONCAT(
'+41',
RIGHT(
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(sourceField['Natel'], ".", ""), ")", ""), " ", ""), "-", ""), ".", ""), "/", ""),
9
)
)

oh it might be because I dont see MID listed as an available function in data cloud formulas :-(

As per the comment too, here's the full formula try this and it should work for your use case:
CONCAT('+41', MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(sourceField['Telefon_P'], ".", ""), "/", ""), " ", ""), "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), 2, LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(sourceField['Telefon_P'], ".", ""), "/", ""), " ", ""), "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", "")) - 1))

